# Detect 32-bit install of program on a 64-bit system

Tags: visual-studio-2013, x86, installation

VB.NET Winforms Program, .NET 4.0, compiled with VS2013.  100% managed code; no DLL that depend on a certain processor architecture.

I have two Visual Studio Installer projects, one for x86 and the other for x64.

The program "phones home" to find a new program; right now I detect the **processor architecture** to determine, if a new program exists, to download the 32-bit or 64 bit installers.

Detection code:

```
    dim sArchitecture as String = ""
    If Environment.Is64BitProcess Then
        sArchitecture = "x64"
    Else
        sArchitecture = "x86"
    End If
```

Problem scenario:

Customer has 64 bit machine but downloads 32 bit installer, which of course works properly.  In fact, we advise customers who do not know their processor architecture to download the 32 bit installer.

32-bit installer program phones home and sends the x64 processor architecture it detects in the program.  Download brings in 64-bit installer, which installs a **second** copy of the program into the customer's computer and confusion ensues.

What I need to figure out, if I use a Visual Studio installer project, with a TargetPlatform set to x86, is there some reliable way to detect this?  Checking the install folder to see if it contains "Program Files (x86)" is insufficient; the customer may have installed the program to another location.

I would truly appreciate the Help!

Thanks
John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the Release build and right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab.  You have the Platform target set to AnyCPU and the Prefer 32-bit checkbox turned off.

Yes, very convenient that .NET program can automatically run in 32-bit and 64-bit mode.  You don't need separate builds for the 32-bit and the 64-bit version, nice.  Other than that your "detection code" no longer works reliably, the 32-bit installer still deploys a program that runs in 64-bit mode.  The only way to discover what installer was used if it does not leave a bread crumb is to reverse-engineer it from the install directory.  Yes, not very reliable.  Leaving a bread crumb in the registry is otherwise very easy to do, installers are good at writing registry keys.

But just simplify your life, you just don't need a 64-bit specific installer at all.  One gets the job done.  That it is stored in the "wrong" directory just doesn't matter, you already know it works fine.

Comment: Thanks.  A thought-provoking answer.  I will choose a solution and report back.